# Make a droppable div expand when elements are dropped inside it. using draggable jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi I have a draggable div and a droppable  div and I would like it so that when i drop a div in the droppable div, the dropable div expands to contain the dropped div. Now it is overflowing. I tried implementing an outer wrapppe. I also tried implementing display:inline block because I heard that if you do that to a parent the size of the parent would be the inner content.

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#draggable2").draggable({
        // opacity : 0.7, 
        helper:"clone",
        scope: 1,
        start: function(e, ui){
            $(ui.helper).addClass("drag-helper");
            console.log(ui);
        }
    })
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(){
            var cloned = $("#draggable2").clone().css({"margin" : "0"})
            $(this).css("background-color" , "green");
            if($(".outerwrapper").length == 0){
                $(this).wrapInner("<div class = 'outerwrapper'></div>");                    
            }
                $(".outerwrapper").append(cloned)

        },
        scope: 1
    })
});
```

CSS:

```
#draggable2{
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
padding: 0.5em;
border :5px solid gray;
background-color: red;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 50px;
vertical-align:middle; 
}
#droppable{
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
padding: 0.5em;
border :5px solid black;
background-color: #777;
display: inline-block;  
vertical-align:middle; 
}
.drag-helper{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
padding: 0.5em;
border :5px solid gray;
background-color: red;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 50px;
vertical-align:middle; 
opacity: 0.5;
border-radius: 100%;        
}
.outerwrapper{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/zLzR9/) shows that when you drag and drop the draggable div multiple times over the drop box they overflow. I want them to be contained. I may want them to be contained horizontally or vertically. so maybe they could be floated left inside the outer container or stacked on top of each other going down the div.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this:

```
$(this).css("height", "100%");
```

to your jQuery code after the:

```
$(".outerwrapper").append(cloned)
```

Here is the edited JSFiddle for your review:  http://jsfiddle.net/zLzR9/1/

Answer (score 1):

just change this line of css:

```
#droppable {
        …
        height: 120px;
        …
    }
```

to :

```
#droppable {
        …
        min-height: 120px;
        …
    }
```

The same will work for width.